# Use of the Phrase "In sequel" to begin a sentence

Tags: questions

Is Using the phrase "In sequel" (making referrence to something in the past) correct in a sentence. For instance:

" In sequel" to our previous conversation, I sent a Forward mail to your box...

Answer (score 1):

No: this is not used in standard English. You need the word **following:**

> Following our previous conversation, ...

That said, it's possible that your use of "In sequel" may have gained currency in a particular dialect or form of English — possibly as a literal translation from another language — but I couldn't find it licensed by a dictionary.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sequel) licenses "In the sequel", but this has the specific meaning of "as things develop in the future" and it's marked as formal use. It is certainly **not** common. This use of *sequel* is almost certainly derived from Latin (cf. *et seq., = et sequens, et sequentes,* "and what follows") and should only be used in contexts where its Latin root will be readily understood.

> *formal* As things develop:
>   *‘this modification of style, as will become clearer **in the sequel,** does not invalidate our earlier approach’*